# Javascript line around a circle

Tags: javascript, canvas, line, bezier, pi

I want to programm this cool visualization with javascrip:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oYMXS.jpg

I have this: http://test.wikunia.de/pi/ but unfortunately I have no idea how to draw the lines that there is a black circle in the middle. Any idea?
I am using quadraticCurveTo now, but maybe bezier curve is a better option...

My full code:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var color_arr = new Array("yellow","orange","OrangeRed","red","violetred","MediumSlateBlue","blue","aquamarine","green","greenyellow");
var sA = (Math.PI / 180) * 270;
var pA = (Math.PI / 180) * 36;
if (canvas && canvas.getContext) {
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  if (ctx) {
  ctx.fillStyle = "black";
  ctx.fillRect(0,0,ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);



  for (var i=0; i <= 9; i++) {
      ctx.strokeStyle = color_arr[i];
      ctx.lineWidth = 5;
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc (350,  350,  250,  sA+(i)*pA,  sA+(i+1)*pA,  false);
      ctx.stroke();
      ctx.closePath();
      ctx.fillStyle = "white";
      ctx.strokeStyle = "white";
      ctx.font = "italic 30pt Arial";
      if (i > 4 && i < 8) {
        ctx.fillText(i.toString(), 350+290*Math.cos(sA+(i+0.5)*pA),350+290*Math.sin(sA+(i+0.5)*pA));
      } else {
        if (i == 3 || i == 4 || i == 8) {
            ctx.fillText(i.toString(), 350+275*Math.cos(sA+(i+0.5)*pA),350+275*Math.sin(sA+(i+0.5)*pA));
        } else {
            ctx.fillText(i.toString(), 350+260*Math.cos(sA+(i+0.5)*pA),350+260*Math.sin(sA+(i+0.5)*pA));
        }
      }
  }




  var pi = '31415...';
  for (i = 0; i <= 250; i++) {
      line(parseInt(pi.substr(i,1)),parseInt(pi.substr(i+1,1)));
  }
}
}

function line(no_1,no_2) {
  var rand_1 = Math.random();
  var rand_2 = Math.random();
  var grad= ctx.createLinearGradient(350+250*Math.cos(sA+(no_1+rand_1)*pA), 350+250*Math.sin(sA+(no_1+rand_1)*pA), 350+250*Math.cos(sA+(no_2+rand_2)*pA), 350+250*Math.sin(sA+(no_2+rand_2)*pA));
  grad.addColorStop(0, color_arr[no_1]);
  grad.addColorStop(1, color_arr[no_2]);
  ctx.lineWidth = 1;
  ctx.strokeStyle = grad;
  ctx.beginPath();

  ctx.moveTo(350+250*Math.cos(sA+(no_1+rand_1)*pA), 350+250*Math.sin(sA+(no_1+rand_1)*pA));
  ctx.quadraticCurveTo(350,350,350+250*Math.cos(sA+(no_2+rand_2)*pA),350+250*Math.sin(sA+(no_2+rand_2)*pA));
  ctx.stroke();
  }
```

Comment: Well, where is the code? What have you tried? What is wrong with what you tried, and what was the expected result?

Comment: The expected result is http://imgur.com/ZCUW7js what if tried is http://test.wikunia.de/pi/

Comment: How about you just (separately from the lines) draw a black circle in the center? And yes, what do you already have and why doesn't it work? Show us code.

Comment: Then post the code here, so the question is not useless for future visitors.

Comment: I want for exampe that a line from 5 to 0 is a bit curved and not straight through the middle

Comment: I solved it :)
You can see the code here:
http://test.wikunia.de/pi/JS/index.js

Comment: @Wikunia: I suspect you're on the right track, but your code has a glitch in setting the gradient. Interesting question and nice solution! Cheers!

Comment: I found there was a error in firefox with color violetred... now I use the hex code ;)

Answer (score 0):

**Interesting!**

The black circle in the middle is just an absence of curves.

The "lines" are cubic Bezier curves.

The beziers appear to be anchored on both ends to the circle circumference at intervals.

Here's my try at a simplified version of that PI:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/Ju6E8/

*This could be addictive so I'm leaving my attempt simple!*

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; padding:50px; }
    #canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>

<script>
$(function(){

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

    var PI2=Math.PI*2;
    var cx=150;
    var cy=150;
    var r=100;

    ctx.arc(cx,cy,r,0,Math.PI*2);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.stroke();

    for(var a=0;a<PI2;a+=PI2/20){
        ctx.strokeStyle="blue";
        curve(a,PI2/2.5,25);
        ctx.strokeStyle="green";
        curve(a,PI2/5,50);
        ctx.strokeStyle="red";
        curve(a,PI2/10,75);
    }

    function curve(rotation,offset,innerRadius){
        var x1=cx+r*Math.cos(rotation);
        var y1=cy+r*Math.sin(rotation);
        var x2=cx+innerRadius*Math.cos(rotation+offset/3.5);
        var y2=cy+innerRadius*Math.sin(rotation+offset/3.5);
        var x3=cx+innerRadius*Math.cos(rotation+offset/1.5);
        var y3=cy+innerRadius*Math.sin(rotation+offset/1.5);
        var x4=cx+r*Math.cos(rotation+offset);
        var y4=cy+r*Math.sin(rotation+offset);
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(x1,y1);
        ctx.bezierCurveTo(x2,y2,x3,y3,x4,y4);
        ctx.stroke();
    }


    $("#stop").click(function(){});

}); // end $(function(){});
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <button id="stop">Stop</button><br>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```